# Why doesn't my http request work for long JSON string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

```
var http = require('http');
var qhttp = require('q-io/http');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var categories;

qhttp.read("https://api.myjson.com/bins/509wa")
 .then(function (json) {
  categories = JSON.parse(json).categories;
 })
 .then(null, console.error);


module.exports.putCat = function(req, res){

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req, function(error, fields, files){
        if(error){console.log(error)}
        fields["catProd"] = [];
        categories.push(fields);

        var dataString = JSON.stringify({categories: categories});
        console.log(dataString);
        var options = {
            host : "api.myjson.com",
            path : "/bins/509wa.json",
            method: "PUT",
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Content-Length": dataString.length}
        };

        function callback(response){
            var body = "";
            response.on('data', function(chunk){
               body+=chunk; 
            });
            response.on('end', function(){
                console.log('Received data: '+body);
            });
        }

        http.request(options, callback).write(dataString);
        res.end();
    });
};
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0UoI.png)

It works perfectly with something like `JSON.stringify("hello":"world");`. However, when I tried with my data that needs to be stored (which is much longer), it doesn't send anything to the API. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should paste your code here, it's more readable than the image. You should also provide the string that doesn't work along with the response you're getting.

Comment: Post your code as code, not as a screenshot.

Comment: You will have to show us the code for the actual case that doesn't work as you say ***"where my data needs to be stored (which are much longer)"***.

Comment: `categories` is undefined here, must be some random global...as is `formidable` as is `http.request`

Comment: oh sorry sorry I'll add the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a race condition with the `categories` variable.   If some external code calls `putCat()` quickly after loading the module, then the `categories` data may not be available yet.

If you have async module loading things to do, then you should probably expose a module constructor which returns a promise and you can then do the `putCat()` after that promise resolves.

Comment: @StanleyNguyen - Did you understand this issue?